# Saving radiobutton value to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

Im trying to take some selected value to use it in an insert method I have to the database (this is working with given vaalues), now I want to give to take the value from a form. Everything's fine but the radio buttons... I do not know how to take the value :P.

Here it is:

```
    <tr>
        <td>Oral/Written Communications:</td>
        <td>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="form1_1" GroupName="form1" runat="server" Text="1" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="form1_2" GroupName="form1" runat="server" Text="2" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="form1_3" GroupName="form1" runat="server" Text="3" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="form1_4" GroupName="form1" runat="server" Text="4" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="form1_5" GroupName="form1" runat="server" Text="5" />
            <br /></td>
    </tr>
```

And in the backend...

```
int selected = form1.value
```

This is not working... Not even recognizing the form1. etc.... How can I handle this?

EB.

Comment: Can you post the class name from your form backend?... or better, the relevant code from your backend code? a single line it's not that useful

Answer (score 0):

When you work with a RadioButton control, each one of them is a separate control and you need to check them like this:

```
string selectedValue;
if (form1_1.Checked)
    selectedValue = form1_1.Text;
else if (form1_2.Checked)
    selectedValue = form1_2.Text;
...
```

You can also go after the Request.Form collection, but I don't find it to be easy to use with RadioButton controls.

Maybe the easiest thing, if you can change the code slightly, is to use a RadioButtonList control:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="form1list" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="4" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="5" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then you can simply refer to the control as a whole:

```
form1list.SelectedValue
```

Comment: Thanks, really. Just one question... Shouldn´t I add a value="1" (each number) to all of the ListItems?

Comment: By default the Value will be the same as the Text property. Only when you need to show the user one content (like a description) but collect another (like an ID) you need to set the Value property.